# How can I remove influence of setting color in mesh's material in Three.js?

Tags: three.js

First I set material's map (simple texture) and color for the mesh

mesh.material.map = ....
mesh.material.color.set('#ff0000');

Then I want to set another texture

mesh.material.map = ....

The mesh became red, but texture is blue for example

How can I remove color from material?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want that the `color` property to affect the texture's color, set it to its default value white. Meaning:

```js
mesh.material.color.set( 0xffffff );
```

That works because the material's color and the sampled color of the diffuse texture are multiplied in order to produce the fragment's final color value.